# Joining based on condition per row

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table as such:

```
|testNr    |date        | 
|1         | 2014-01-01 |
|2         | 2014-01-03 |
|3         | 2014-01-03 |
```

And another one like:

```
|finalID   | testNr     | from_date   |to_date 
|1         | 1          | 2013-12-01  |2013-12-20
|2         | 1          | 2013-12-25  |2014-01-05
|3         | 2          | 2014-01-01  |2014-01-05
```

I want to lookup the `finalID` from the second table and join it with the first. It is imporant that the `date` in the first column is between the date range in the second column.

I would like to end up with:

```
|testNr    |date        | finalID
|1         | 2014-01-01 | 2
|2         | 2014-01-03 | 3
|3         | 2014-01-03 | NULL
```

I am using SQL server. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
select t1.testNr, t1.date, t2.finalID
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
on t1.testNr=t2.testNr and t1.date between t2.from_date and t2.to_date
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be125/2)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
 SELECT t1.*, t2.finalID 
 FROM table1 t1
 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.testNR=t2.testNR and t1.[date] between t2.from_date and t2.to_date
```

[SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02348/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.*,T2.FINALID FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.TESTNR=T2.TESTNR
AND T1.DATE BETWEEN T2.FROM_DATE AND T2.TO_DATE
```